# "Invalid Column Name" When Column Exists

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pymssql

I am repeatedly running into a problem using pymssql and pandas to read SQL Server queries in Python 3.7.

When I run the query below as part of my Python script, I get an error `Invalid Column Name 'RecID'.` I do not get this error when running the same query by itself in SQL Server Management Studio. I can also avoid the error if I do not include #Archives in the statement that creates #Union. However, running `select * from #Archives` by itself or in the Python script works fine and shows that the column `RecID` does exist in that table.

```
query="""
set nocount on
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted

if object_id('tempdb..#Files') is not null drop table #Files
if object_id('tempdb..#Archives') is not null drop table #Archives
if object_id('tempdb..#Recs') is not null drop table #Recs
if object_id('tempdb..#Union') is not null drop table #Union

--  Get Files
select FileLogID as FileSubmitGroupID, p.FileName, convert(date, p.LoadDate) LoadDate
into #Files
from tFileLog f
join (select max(LoadDate) LoadDate, FileName from tFileLog where LoadDate >= '2021-05-01' group by FileName) p
on p.Loaddate = f.LoadDate and p.FileName = f.FileName


--  Get Archive Records
select a.StageID as RecID, a.FileLogID as FileSubmitGroupID, FileName, convert(date, a.LoadDate) LoadDate
into #Archives
from ABCArchive..tStageArchive a
join #Files f on a.FileLogID = f.FileSubmitGroupID 


--  Compile list of records from Archive, Error and ALL tables
select pa.ItemID as RecID, f.FileSubmitGroupID, FileName, f.LoadDate
into #Union
from CompanyBase..P_ALL pa
join #Files f on pa.FileSubmitGroupID = f.FileSubmitGroupID

union all

select RecID, FileSubmitGroupID, FileName, convert(date, LoadDate) LoadDate
from #Archives 

union all

select e.StageID as RecID, f.FileSubmitGroupID, f.FileName, f.LoadDate
from tStageError e
join #Files f on e.FileLogID = f.FileSubmitGroupID 
...
"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, con, parse_dates=['LoadDate'])
```

I've tried aliasing RecID differently, I've tried creating `#Archives` with a `CREATE TABLE` statement, and I've tried using `select * from #Archives` to created the `#Union` table. These methods either don't prevent the error or introduce new ones. It seems as if this code simply does not like the first column of the #Archives table and does not want to admit it exists.

What am I missing?

**ETA:** The query now runs as expected, though I can't figure out what the underlying problem was.

I simply ran the query on ABCArchive as part of the `#Union` query, without creating a temp table `#Archives` first. Was there something wrong with how I created the temp table that caused the RecID column to glitch? Or should I just be glad the code gremlins have been expelled?

Comment: Have you tried running **just** `SELECT * FROM #Archives` after the insert to see the columns returned? That may shed some insight.

Comment: I did, and it returns RecID, FileSubmitGroupID, FileName and LoadDate, as expected.

Comment: Silly question: What happens if you change the order of the columns into #Union? Same error with a different column name?

Comment: Tried changing the order of the columns, and it still hates RecID.